# NodeJS response.write inside callback

Tags: node.js

I'm using a route to process a url.  The functions fire as expected.  What I'm trying to do is use the response.write() inside of a call back.  I understand this isn't working because the call back doesn't have access to the same variables as the function that calls it, but I'm wondering what the correct NODE way of doing this would be.

```
route.post('/{type}subject/{method}', function (request,response) {
var post = "";
request.on('data', function (chunk){
    post += chunk;
});
request.on('end', function (){
    postData = qs.parse(post);
    response.writeHead(200);
    switch(request.params['method'].toLowerCase())
    {
        case "registerobserver":
            if (postData['uri']){
                registerObserver (request.params['type'], postData['uri']);
                response.write(success("registerobserver"));
            }
            else
                response.write(failure("1","uri undefined"));

            break;
        case "unregisterobserver":
            if (postData['uri']){
                client.query ('DELETE observers FROM observers INNER JOIN type ON (observers.TypeID = type.TypeID) WHERE observers.uri ="'+postData['uri']+'" AND type.name = "'+request.params['type']+'"', 
                function(err, info) 
                {
                    if(err){
                        response.write(failure("2", "general database failure"));}
                    else{   
                    if(info.affectedRows != 0)
                        response.write(success("unregisterobserver")); //this code does not trigger a response due to namespace

                    else
                        response.write(failure("1", "uri not an observer"));//this code does not trigger a response
                        console.log("uri not observer");
                    }

                    console.log("done");
                })

            }
            else
                response.write(failure("1","uri required"));

            break;
        default:

    }

    response.end();
})
//response.write("type: "+request.params['type']+"<br/>method="+request.params['method']);

});

function success(method){return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<response stat=\"ok\">\n\t<method>"+method+"</method>\n</response>";}
function failure(code, message){return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<response stat=\"fail\">\n\t<err code=\""+code+"\" msg = \""+message+"\" />\n</response>";}
```

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect; an anonymous function can use variables from its parent.  The problem is that the response may have been sent before the callback runs.  (it's async)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically what happens is that the async `query` handler function will be called *after* your `response.end()` function call. As such any writes will fail.

You need to call `response.end()` from inside the callback instead, and take care to not otherwise call `response.end()` once you are in async code path. Ie. `return` immediately after the `client.query()` call.

Comment: Doh.  Your response makes perfect sense.  Thanks for reviewing the code, I'll post after making the change. Silly event driven-ness.

Comment: Marked as answer -- moving response.end() to after each response.write call performed as expected.  Thank you both.