# NodeJS unable to response.write to the browser when there is delay in callbacks

Tags: model-view-controller, mongodb, node.js

i'm using simple MVC structure by Nathan Broslawsky. i have these code below.

```
ArticleProviderDBController.prototype.Show = function(data) {
//Init Model
var res = this.Response;
var model = this.getModel();
var view = this.getView("ArticleProviderDB");

model.findAll(function(error, article_collections){
        if( error ) console.log(error);
        view.renderGH(res, data, article_collections); //this will actually call the renderGH function to serve a html file with data from DB but it is not working.
        res.write('inside callback'); //this will not.
        //res.end();
}); 
//console.log(_self.Response);
res.write('outside callback'); //this will be shown on my browser.
//res.end();
```

}

actually i try to follow what people have done using expressjs

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){
    res.render('index.jade', { 
        locals: {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles:docs
        }
    });
})
```

});

but seems like it is not working.

i also saw a post [NodeJS response.write not working within callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232157/nodejs-response-write-inside-callback) posted recently but his solution is not working for me. My main objective is to use simple MVC structure created with Nodejs without the use of other templates such as expressjs to serve html with DB query. thank you.